# I have a code calculating postfix equations using stack in c but I get some weird interactions

Tags: c, struct, postfix-notation

I made a program calculating postfix equations but something is going wrong when entering the `while` loop and I don't know why.

I tried to see what is going wrong, so I put a `printf` statement over each step in order to find the problem. My pointer `t` gets the value of the first address in my table `exp`. Here is where things goes wrong.

Before entering the `while` loop ,to see if `*t` contains a digit or not, the value is as expected. After entering the loop it becomes random numbers but always end in the value -1 for a reason I don't know and this messes up my entire program. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include "MyStack.h"

int main(){

    int i = 0, *t, exp[N], stack[N];    
    char c;
    int n1, n2, obj;
    printf ("Give postfix formula for evaluation:"); 

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n'){
        exp[i] = c - 48;
        printf("%d\n", exp[i]);
        i++;
    }
    t = exp;
    printf("\nValue of pointer t %d\n",*t);
    while(*t != '\n'){
        printf("\nValue of pointer t after entering the loop %d\n",*t);
        if(isdigit(*t)){
            obj = *t - 48;
            printf("%d\n", obj);
            push(stack, t, obj);
        }
        else{
            n1 = pop(stack, t);
            n2 = pop(stack, t);
            switch(*t){
                case '+': push(stack, t, n1 + n2); break;
                case '-': push(stack, t, n1 - n2); break;
                case '*': push(stack, t, n1 * n2); break;
                case '/': {
                    if(n1 == 0){
                        printf("Division with 0 is not eligible\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    else push(stack, t, n2 / n1); break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    printf ("%d\n",exp[i]);

    printf("\nThe result of expression %s  =  %d\n\n",exp,pop(stack, t));
    return 0; 
}

void push(int stack [], int *t, int obj)
{
    if ((*t) == (N - 1))
    {
        printf("Stack overflow...\n");
        getch();
        abort();
    }
    else stack[++(*t)] = obj;
}

int pop(int stack[], int *t)
{
    int r;
    if ((*t) < 0)
    {
        printf("Stack empty...\n");
        printf("Error in expression\n");
        getch();
        abort();
    }
    else r = stack[(*t)--];
    return (r);
}
```

`"MyStack.h"` contains the libraries I need and the declaration of functions `pop` and `push`. Ideally, `*t` should contain the first digit, then pushing it into `stack` and then keep on pushing in the next digits until `*t` points to an operator. There it should pop out the last 2 digits pushed from the `stack`, do the operation and return the result in the ```stuck``. 
But instead [this happens http://prntscr.com/nrf7b9](http://prntscr.com/nrf7b9)

As you can see although it gets the correct value it keeps on looping and changing values till it becomes -1 then proceeding to `isdigit` function.

Comment: This seems like a perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Using simple [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) I found quite a few problems with your code. I also recommend you take a couple of steps back, and take some time to read your books, tutorials or class notes on how passing arguments to functions work.

Comment: if `t` is supposed to act as stack top you should not be pointing it to `t = exp;`? Also it should not be `pointer` normal variable should do the task. While passing to `push` or `pop` pass its address.

Comment: `else{...}` pops 2 arguments even for characters like `' '`, `'-'`.  Post true input used and output seen.

Comment: Found it, my problem were located on my head, I was so biased on "what I am doing is right" that I totally forgot about ```*t``` was the top of my stack. Made a new pointer to pass on the characters from ```exp``` and it worked perfectly. Thank you both.

As for the passing of pointers as arguements, I am doing it right. I mean, if my variable is already a pointer I don't have to give its address as an arguement, because it is already pointing to one.